# Calculate your total happiness, which depends on the integers in the given sets

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am a beginner in programming. And I am learning python as my first language. I went on to do some challenges on [HackerRank](https://hackerrank.com) and stumbled upon [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/no-idea/problem). The problem goes like this:

> There is an array of \$\ n \$ integers. There are also \$\ 2 \$
>   disjoint sets , \$\ A \$ and \$\ B \$ each containing \$\ m \$
>   integers. You like all the integers in set \$\ A \$ and dislike all
>   the integers in set \$\ B \$. Your initial happiness is \$\ 0 \$. For
>   each \$\ i \$ integer in the array, if \$\ i \in A\$, you add \$\ 1 \$
>   to your happiness. If \$\ i \in B\$, you add \$\ -1\$ to your
>   happiness. Otherwise, your happiness does not change. Output your
>   final happiness at the end.
>
> **Input Format** 
>  The first line contains integers \$\ n \$ and \$\ m \$ separated by a space. 
>  The second line contains \$\ n \$
>   integers, the elements of the array. 
>  The third and fourth line
>   contains \$\ m \$ integers, of \$\ A \$ and \$\ B \$
>   respectively.
>
> **Output Format** 
>  Output a single integer, your total happiness.
>
> **Sample input** 
>  `3 2 1 5 3 3 1 5 7`
>   **Sample output** `1`

Here's my attempt at the answer. My code is working fine with small inputs but when the values of \$\ n \$ and \$\ m \$ are in millions, it gives a *Terminated due to timeout :(* error. Please help me out with time-efficient code that will execute within the time limits.

```
elems_count = input().split()
my_set = input().split()
happy_set = input().split()
sad_set = input().split()

happy = 0
for i in range(int(elems_count[0])):
    if my_set[i] in happy_set:
        happy = happy + 1 
    else:
        happy = happy - 1
print(happy)
```

Comment: Separate from the performance issue, but you have an error in the loop - it's counting every non-liked number as a disliked number.

Comment: @Errorsatz Thanks for pointing out the error. I fixed it and tried submitting it again on hackerrank, now it fails one case less, than before fixing the error. It still fails 4 of 8 cases giving the `Terminated due to time out error :(`.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: "_Thanks for pointing out the error. I fixed it and tried submitting it again on hackerrank, now it fails one case less, than before fixing the error._"  Since your code was generating failures unrelated to `[time-limit-exeeded]`, this question is off-topic for Code Review.  Code must be working, to the best of the author's knowledge before posting it here.

Comment: (In essence: re-think *testing* your code. Once confident your code is functionally correct, you are welcome to post a new question when you still have concerns about it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by both MrVajid and AJNeufeld, the previous solution (now deleted because it is actually irrelevant now; see post history) actually did not work.
This is because in reality, the task requires the input array to *not* be a set, aka it should be allowed to have duplicate entries.

In fact, I had solved that challenge successfully a while ago, using:

```py
n, m = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

array = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
A = {int(x) for x in input().split()}
B = {int(x) for x in input().split()}

happiness = 0

for value in array:
    change = 1 if value in A else -1 if value in B else 0
    happiness += change

print(happiness)
```

This is using `set` comprehension (`{ }`) and passes just fine on HackerRank.

Iteration over the input array as a `list` is still \$O(n)\$, see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), but containment checks for sets is constant time, \$O(1)\$. Previously, with \$A\$ and \$B\$ being lists, this was also linear as \$O(m)\$, leading to \$O(n*m)\$ aka quadratic time complexity.

Since this task on HackerRank is specifically about `set` usage, it will judge pedantically about time complexity, with only the approach using sets not running into timeout errors.

---

Notice that your solution also has an error apart from the `set` one.
You check for containment in `happy_set` and decrement `happy` for a negative result.
However, you first need to check for containment in `sad_set` first.
Otherwise, you are much sadder than required.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the time complexity analysis and for pointing out the error that makes me much sadder than required. I fixed it and tried submitting it as it is now in the edited question, that still didn't work anyways. `compute_happiness_old` and `compute_happiness_old` both work. It seems like just covering it into `set` does the work. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: You have fixed some problem in the OP's code, but introduced other problems.  From the actual problem link: "_However, the array might contain duplicate elements._"  Turning the input array into a set is going to remove duplicates, so if the array contained duplicate happy/sad numbers, those numbers will only count +/- 1, instead of once per occurrence.  Your test case cannot generate any duplicate number in the array due to the `random.sample()`, so hides this issue.

Comment: That is true, but to what degree should questions on here be self-sufficient? In any case, I now rewrote the answer and confirmed it works on HackerRank.